# Replace text in a large text document using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace text in a large text document that follows this pattern.

```
set @{VariableName} = dbo.XmlAssignAttributeValues({VariableName}, '/{NodeName}', '{PropertyName}', @{PropertyVariableName})
```

Examples:

```
set @Xml = dbo.XmlAssignAttributeValues(@Xml, '/Xml','xmlAssemblyTimeInMilliseconds', @XmlAssemblyTimeInMilliseconds)
```

Into...

```
set @Xml.modify('insert attribute xmlAssemblyTimeInMilliseconds {sql:variable("@XmlAssemblyTimeInMilliseconds")} into  (/Xml)[1]')
```

This...

```
set @StudentsXml = dbo.XmlAssignAttributeValues(@StudentsXml, '/Students', 'studentCount', @StudentCount)
```

Into..

```
set @StudentsXml.modify('insert attribute studentCount {sql:variable("@StudentCount")} into  (/Students)[1]')
```

This...

```
set @ClassesXml = dbo.XmlAssignAttributeValues(@ClassesXml, '/Classes', 'ClassRank', @SomeSillyClassRank)
```

Into...

```
set @ClassesXml.modify('insert attribute ClassRank {sql:variable("@SomeSillyClassRank")} into  (/Classes)[1]')
```

**Edit #1 For further clarification:**
So within my text document I have alot of SQL expressions that interact with XML attributes. So in the expression set @{VariableName} = dbo.XmlAssignAttributeValues({VariableName}, '/{NodeName}', '{PropertyName}', @{PropertyVariableName}) I have a variable name that is assigned to my database in a function called dbo.XmlAssignAttributeValues. In that function the parameters that are passed are the variable name I'm setting "@Xml", the name of the node I'm trying to access '/NodeName', the property name I'm trying to insert into and the properties DB variable name.

Thus, what I need to do l is look for the string that follows the format "set @TheVariableName = dbo.XmlAssignAttributeValues(@TheVariableName, '/TheNodeName', 'ThePropertyName', @ThePropertiesVariableName" TO "set @AnyVariableName.modify('@TheVariableName ThePropertyName{sql:variable("@ThePropertiesVariableName")} into (/TheNodeName)[1]') Hopefully that clears things up more!

How do I do this using regex in C#?

Comment: Can you explain using words what you are trying to do? It's difficult to reverse engineer the rules from your examples.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Certainly! So within my text document I have alot of SQL expressions that interact with XML attributes. So in the expression 

set @{VariableName} = dbo.XmlAssignAttributeValues({VariableName}, '/{NodeName}', '{PropertyName}', @{PropertyVariableName})

I have a variable name that is assigned to my database in a function called dbo.XmlAssignAttributeValues. In that function the parameters that are passed are the variable name I'm setting "@Xml", the name of the node I'm trying to access '/NodeName', the property name I'm trying to insert into and the properties DB variable name

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add those details - the formatting is much better.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Implemented Edits!

Answer (score 1):

> How do I do this using regex in C#?

1. You create a regular expression which matches all your inputs. Put those parts of the input that you want to reuse into groups by enclosing them in parenthesis.
2. You call `Regex.Replace` and refer to the groups by using `$1`, `$2`, ...

Example: Say you want to replace text of the form `Set @{VariableName} =` by `Declare {VariableName}`, i.e. `Set @foo =`  should become `Declare foo`. Then you would:

1. Create the regular expression - in this case it would be `^Set @([a-zA-Z0-9]+) =$` and then
2. apply it with `Regex.Replace`:

   ```
   output = Regex.Replace(input, "^Set @([a-zA-Z0-9]+) =$", "Declare $1", 
                          RegexOptions.Multiline);
   ```

   Since your text document contains multiple lines, you need to use the `Multiline` option to ensure that `^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of a *line*, respectively, instead of the beginning and the end of the document itself.

Applying this technique to the remainder your example is left as an exercise. For the first step, note that there are [lots of online regex testers available](https://www.google.at/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=regex%20tester), which can help you to iteratively build your regular expression.

Comment: Thank you! So to clarify my 2nd input in Regex. Replace will eventually be the full length regex expression I want to use?

Comment: @BenJohnson: Exactly.